# How do I append a string containing a style tag as-is to the document head with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I'm asynchronously rendering a template serverside with [rapscallion](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/rapscallion) in node. At the point of rendering the body, I have a string (containing line breaks) that needs to be inserted in the document head:

```
// this is what I have serverside
var stylestring = `<style type="text/css" data-style="some-id-that needs to be preserved">
.lfwARz {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
</style>`
```

Since at that point I've already sent the `<head>` to the client, I need to insert a script that sets these styles to the head clientside. But I'm having trouble getting this to work.

This approach works:

```
// gets run clientside
<script>
  var style = document.createElement('style')
  style.type = 'text/css'
  style.innerHTML = '${() => sheet.getStyleTags().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/<\/?style.*?>/g, '')}'
  document.head.appendChild(style)
</script>
```

But it results in a loss of the data attribute (which I need to preserve so the styles won't get rerendered on the client).

Comment: How are you rendering the template exactly?

Comment: @Halcyon I'm using node and [rapscallion](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/rapscallion). What I'm doing is basically this: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/rapscallion#example

Comment: Can you do something like `document.head.appendChild(style_element)`?

Comment: @Halcyon No, because it is not a valid dom element yet. I only have a string with `'<style type="text/css">llfwARz { ...etc'`.

Comment: @Halcyon So if I do `document.head.appendChild(style_string)` I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.createElement('div')` then insert the string to it, get the DOM from that fragment so that it can be inserted to the `<head>` using `appendChild`:

```
var fragment = document.createElement('div');
// remove newlines from the string and insert it in the fragment
fragment.innerHTML = the_style_string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');
document.head.appendChild(fragment.firstChild);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the string already contains the style tags though. So this won't work. I'd rather parse it to an element directly, if that's possible.

Comment: try this: `document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + '<style type="text/css"> body{background: red}<style>'`

Comment: @vsjn3290ckjnaoij2jikndckjb Updated the answer.

Comment: I've tested your answer. It fails with: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: Then, I would simply set a hard-coded `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section with specific ID and update its inner HTML through its ID: `document.getElementById('dynamic-style').innerHTML=the_style_string.replace(/<\/?style.*?>/g, "");`. This is the simplest alternative.

Comment: @TaufikNurrohman Problem is, there are some data-attributes on the style tag that I need to preserve. Otherwise the styles will be rerendered on the client. So removing the outer style tags would also result in me losing those data attributes. Otherwise, your approach would work..

Comment: Ah, so using your `document.createElement('div')` approach works. The `document.createDocumentFragment();` approach doesn't (as said it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`). The one thing that I needed to add serverside is `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')`, to replace the newlines in the string.